# PhotoShop exports layers to files with bad filenames

Tags: iphone, ios, export, photoshop, retina-display

I use Photoshop script,that export all layers into png files.

[image: Script]

After script successfuly done, in saved folder files have strange filenames, like:
[image: FileNames]

UI-_0000_Background.png

UI-_0001s_0001_Input-Background.png

This is my Layers:

[image: Layes]

Do you know how to save files with what format:

%(Prefix)%(LayerName)%(Additions).png

Like UI-Background@2x.png?

Or if you know another way how to save pngs from photoshop for Retina and non-Retina iPhone displayes, can you describe it, please?

Thx!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is how the plugin supose to work. you should check in the Photoshop menu if there are any other options for this plugin to remove the 0000 and underscore. As sollution you can use IrfanView or similar software to rename your files using regex or special commands so you can remove the underscore and 0000 easely.